# Work on one commit while browsing another (Git/Mercurial)

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

Say I have a huge Git/Mercurial repository with commit/changeset `A` and `B`.

Now say that there are two non overlapping sets of files, say set `dir1` and set `dir2`. Set `dir1` exists in commit/changeset `A`, and may exist in `B`, and vice versa (set `dir2` exists in commit/changeset `B`, and may exist in `A`). For simplicity, let's only consider the special case where `dir1` and `dir2` are fully contained in a subdirectory of the repository.

**Now say I want to browse the set of files `dir1` at commit/changeset `A`, while making changes and commits to the set of files `dir2` at commit/changeset `B`.**

One obvious solution is to make a clone of the repository and update the two repositories to the different points in time. This is fine for most cases, but say my repository is very large and it would be very inefficient and time consuming to clone the repo and maintain two copies.

Another solution would be to `hg update`/`git checkout` to `B` and use `hg cat`/`git show` to view the files as they were in changeset `A`. But say I wanted `dir1` to be on my drive as actual files (for example, I needed to run a non trivial script to batch process the files in `dir1` at `A` and show some output which I then need to make changes at `B`).

Is there a way to achieve this locally within one repository?

Comment: I would suggest you ask about Git or Mercurial, and that you explain why you wouldn't merge the changes together.

Comment: @AndrewC I don't merge the changes together because I am not actually making any changes at changeset `A`, just obtaining information. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface**

You must to know 2 things:

- all files|directories exist in all changesets of repository
- only one active point (parent of working directory) may exist in one repository

**Partial Solution: Mercurial**

If RO changeset as set of static objects, unrelated to repo, is sufficient for you, you can `hg archive` changeset A as tree

`hg archive -r A -t files PATH/TO/RESULT/ROOT`

and work in repo with changeset B

Comment: Thanks, this can be applied to any subset of files at `A` if it is used with the `-I` or `-X` switch, so `hg archive -r A -t files -I /path/to/dir1 PATH/TO/RESULT/ROOT` does the trick

Answer (score 2):

Lazy Badger has a perfect answer for you, that you've wisely selected, but just to make sure you know that a 2nd local clone wouldn't take up as much space as you're imagining in Mercurial because Mercurial uses hardlinks to avoid taking up extra disk space.  Here's an example:

```
hg clone http://host/really-big-repo
hg clone -r B really-big-repo copy-of-really-big-repo
```

If you do that the first clone will have the full history and a checkout of the files.  The 2nd one will use hardlinks to point to the full history of the local clone and a copy of the files.  So you're still using the space taken up by a copy of the files at changeset B, but you're not taking up any additional space for the repo.

In general though, if you have a single repo w/ two unrelated projects in them (just a guess) you should split them into two separate repos.